# One child report is shared across multiple parent reports, if i make a change in the child report will it affect all the parent reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm very new to crystal report.

One child report is shared across multiple parent reports, if i make a change in the child report will it affect all the parent reports?

A B C D are the parent reports and Z is the child report

If make a change in Z will it affect All parent reports.
Or will have to manually change in each Parent reports

Child report means Sub-report

Comment: parent reports means all different reports and one report won't have any relation to other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "child report" do you mean subreport ?
If this is what you mean you need to check if the subreport is marked for Re-import when the main report is open. Right click on the subreport and select menu "Format Subreport", select the last tab "Subreport" and find check box "Re-Import When Opening"
If the subreport is set to be reimported and the subreport file is at the same path as when it was initially imported any change in the subreport will be imported in the main report during the next load.

Comment: simple and neat explanation. +1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are using that child report in all parent reports then it will affect all parents reports when you view them.